# How to pass object reference to an event handler within a dart polymer element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

**Can I pass not only String attributes but also object references to an event handler?**

Sample gwt_contacts from https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples:

contacts_view.html:

```html
<div id="contact-list">
  <template repeat="{{contacts}}">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span on-click="selectContact" data-id="{{id}}">{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

handler in contacts_view.dart

```dart
void selectContact(MouseEvent event, var detail, SpanElement target) {
  String id = target.attributes["data-id"];
  selectedContact = contacts.firstWhere((Contact contact) => contact.id == id);
}
```

**How can I pass the contact reference instead of the ID?**

similar question: [How do I pass arbitrary data to a click event handler function from a Dart polymer web component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249077/how-do-i-pass-arbitrary-data-to-a-click-event-handler-function-from-a-dart-polym/18249085#18249085)

CHANGED:

With the hint of Christophe Herreman I added a new element:

html:

```html
<polymer-element name="contact-view-item">
  <template>
    <span on-click="select">{{contact.name}}</span>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

dart:

```dart
@CustomTag("contact-view-item")
class ContactViewItem extends PolymerElement {
  @observable @published Contact contact;

  void select(MouseEvent event, var detail, var target) {
    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("contactselected", detail: contact));
  }
}
```

and changed the list to:

```html
<div id="contact-list">
  <template repeat="{{contact in contacts}}">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <contact-view-item contact="{{contact}}" on-contactselected="contactSelectedHandler"></contact-view-item>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

and added the handler to ContactsView:

```dart
void contactSelectedHandler(CustomEvent event) {
  selectedContact = event.detail;
}
```

But dispatching the custom event will throw an error:

```
Uncaught Error: unsupported object type for conversion
Exception: unsupported object type for conversion
undefined (undefined:0:0)
```

The connection seems to be fine, because if I don't pass contact as detail than contactSelectedHandler will be called, but detail is - of course - null.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible declaratively from within the HTML definition. You can dispatch an object in the `detail` property of a `CustomEvent`, when you dispatch it from the element class. Note that the `detail` property is actually just a reference to `event.detail` when event is a `CustomEvent`. If not, the `detail` property is null.

**Component definition**

```html
<div id="contact-list">
  <template repeat="{{contacts}}">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span on-click="contact_clickHandler" data-id="{{id}}">{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

```dart
void contact_clickHandler(MouseEvent event, var detail, SpanElement target) {
  String id = target.attributes["data-id"];
  Contact contact = contacts.firstWhere((Contact c) => c.id == id);
  dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("contactselected", detail: selectedContact));
}
```

**Component usage**

```html
<contact-list on-contactselected="contactList_contactSelectedHandler"></contact-list>
```

```dart
void contactList_contactSelectedHandler(CustomEvent event) {
  var contact = event.detail;
  // do something with selected contact
}
```

Comment: I thought of a solution create a "child" polymer element, pass the object as attribute and propagate the event to the parent with this object. Do you mean such a solution? But I don't know how to implement this correct

Comment: I would just dispatch the custom event containing the selected contact from the element class. The view that uses the component can then simply listen for the custom event and get the contact from the event detail. I added a code example to the answer.

Comment: changed the question - please see above

Comment: There seems to be an open issue regarding this: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11192