# Best way to get model associated with a core-item element?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Consider this Polymer fragment:

```html
<core-menu on-core-activate="{{selectUser}}">
  <template repeat="{{user in users}}">
    <core-item label="{{user.name}}"></core-item>
  </template>
</core-menu>
```

When a user clicks on a `core-item` element and triggers `selectUser`, how do I determine what user is associated with the activated `core-item`? I'd like to get an instance to the actual object, and not some stringified identifier that I would use to look up the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Polymer >= 1.0.0**

```
@reflectable
void someClickHandler(dom.Event event, [_]) {
  // for native events (like on-click)
  var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(event);
  // or for custom events (like on-tap, works also for native events)
  var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(convertToJs(event));
  var value = model.jsElement['items']; 
  // or 
  var value = model.jsElement[$['mylist'].attributes['as']];
  // if you used the `as="somename"` 
  // in your <core-list> or <template is="dom-repeat">
}
```

There is an open issue related to custom events: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/624

**Polymer <= 0.16.0**

In the click handler

```dart
import 'package:template_binding/template_binding.dart' as tb;

...

void onClick(MouseEvent e) {
  tb.TemplateInstance ti = tb.nodeBind(e.target).templateInstance; 
  var value = ti.model.value as Inner;
}
```

see [In Polymer.js children of a template have a reference to the template, how can this be done in Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530054) for more details.

Comment: Man that seems awkward. Is there other way? :/

Comment: Don't think so. You can reduce it to one line (without the import). Some things are not so simple in Dart than in JS ...

Comment: I guess this really is the only way... pretty weak, but it'll do for now.