# Polymer function call with parameters

Tags: polymer

This seems like a very simple one, but somehow I am not sure how to do it.
I want to send data to a Polymer component with the "core-collapse-open" event but this is not working:

```
<core-collapse on-core-collapse-open="{{loadDetails(data)}}">
{{data.Title}}
...
```

When I use the above code, the `loadDetails` function in polymer is not hitting.

```
Polymer('custom-item', {
        data: {},
        ready: function () {
        },   
        loadDetails: function (e, details, sender) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
```

If I am not using the function syntax in the declarative syntax(as below), the loadDetails function hits.

```
<core-collapse on-core-collapse-open="{{loadDetails}}">
{{data.Title}}
...
```

How can I send parameters in events.

Comment: This doesn't look like to be related to Dart. Is there any reason you added the `dart-polymer` tag?

Comment: I was not sure if this was related to Dart. I will remove that now.

Comment: The Polymer 1.x way to do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210278/polymer-event-parameters-on-repeat/31749033#31749033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from my another post. Even though I posted for different context, I understand I can use the same. Thanks Gunter for reply on that thread.

[Polymer event parameters on repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210278/polymer-event-parameters-on-repeat/28211187)

Answer (score 0):

```
on-core-collapse-open="{{loadDetails(data)}}"
```

This means: execute `loadDetails(data)` and whatever the return value of this is will be bound as the event handler. Not what you want.

Also, the event handler function already receives parameters: the event object. You cannot pass it additional parameters. If the `data` you want to pass refers to your `this.data` attribute: the `loadDetails` function already has access to it in the form of `this.data`, so you don't need to pass it.

If you're trying to use the same handler function for two different events and pass additional parameters with each individual event: traditionally you'd do that with an anonymous function wrapper, and that's simply not possible using the declarative syntax.

Comment: data is not this.data. So, I really needed that additional parameters. Let me think if there is any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `data` to an attribute of `core-collapse` and then access the data using the `target` argument of the event handler or the `target` property of the `event` argument or alternatively if `data` is the model of the element anyway just access the `TemplateInstance` (see full example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24530099/217408)