# Polymer: Capture events of child elements from parent

Tags: polymer

I was wondering how I can capture events which occur from a child element from the parent as shown below. I know this method works to capture events using `this` but I need it from the child element.

I don't want to capture the event from the `li` and transfer information to `foo` through global variables or other such means because I'll ultimately be implementing a `mousemove` event which sends the position of the mouse per trigger, and it would be extremely inefficient sending this through the global variables technique (like as demonstrated in the API [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global)) and slow down the app.

```
<polymer-element name="foo">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <li>This is my child element</li>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('foo', {
      ready: function() {
        document.querySelector('li').addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
            console.log('mousedown event working');
        })
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight you may provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `document.querySelector()` because your `li` element is inside the [shadow dom](https://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html) of the Polymer element. Btw. the element name is incorrect, [it must contain a dash](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html#createpolyel).

You can use the [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding) feature of Polymer to get the `li` element. Assign an id to the element and use the `this.$` property (alternatively if you don't want to assign an id, you can use `this.shadowRoot.querySelector()`):

```
<li id="item">This is my child element</li>

this.$.item.addEventListener(...);
```

But with Polymer you can [declaratively assign the callback function](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping) to the `li` element, which results in a much more readable code:

```
<polymer-element name="my-foo">
    <template>
        <ul>
            <li on-mousedown="{{mousedown}}">This is my child element</li>
        </ul>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-foo', {
            mousedown: function() {
                    console.log('mousedown event working');
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know of any way to pass a variable through the `{{mousedown}}` in `<li on-mousedown="{{mousedown}}">This is my child element</li>` like you would a normal js function?

Comment: You could [pass values to your handler with `data-` attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249077/how-do-i-pass-arbitrary-data-to-a-click-event-handler-function-from-a-dart-polym/18249085#18249085).

Comment: I tried this and got `[client-panel::_createEventHandler]: listener method {{mousedown}} not defined` warning in console and didn't work. I removed curly brackets and it worked.